# How to reset an uploaded file once a button has been pressed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-canvas, fabricjs

On my website the user can draw on an uploaded image. I've added a button to clear the canvas completely but the issue with this is that if the user wanted to draw on this image again they cant as the upload button still thinks its there.
see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmDt6.jpg

im using vue and fabric for the canvas

here is what i have

```
    <b-field position="is-centered" class="file">
      <b-upload required accept="image/*" v-model="filename">
        <a class="button is-primary">
          <b-icon icon="upload"></b-icon>
          <span>Click to upload</span>
        </a>
      </b-upload>
      <span class="file-name" v-if="filename">{{ displayFileName }}</span>
      <a class="button is-primary" v-on:click="clearArtboard">
        <span>Clear</span>
      </a>
```

my clear canvas method has only this. ( i assume i need to add something here?)

```
    clearArtboard() {
      var canvas = this.__canvas;
      canvas.clear();
    },
```

this is triggered when the file is uploaded

```
    async filename(file) {
      this.$Progress.start();
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", file);
      data.append("upload_preset", "");
      const res = await fetch(
        "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1//image/upload",
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: data
        }
      );
      const uploadedFile = await res.json();
```

so how do i make it so the upload button thinks there is no file uploaded when i press clear? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like more of a `<input type="file">` question than a VueJS one.

The file input provides javascript an API to read a file from the browser. The file input is not inherently aware of a) whether you're uploading it or not or b) how to react once such a process has been completed.

As a consequence, what you're missing is some code to clear out the file input once this process has been completed. In short, all you really need is something akin to `fileInput.value = ''`

Since this isn't really a VueJS issue but more of a file input issue, here's a minimal example of this without VueJS.

```js
const upload = document.querySelector('#upload')
const btn = document.querySelector('#upload-btn')

// The 'input' event is fired when a file is selected
upload.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  // In this example, we show the upload button only once a file is chosen
  if (e.target.value) {
    // A file was selected. So enable the upload button
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled')
  } else {
    // No file available. Disable the upload button
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', true)
  }
})

btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  // Do some async work here to pretend to be uploading
  btn.classList.add('is-loading')
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)) // Simply sleeps for 1s
  btn.classList.remove('is-loading')
  upload.value = '' // Reset the file input
  
  // Dispatch the input event so that the other handler will 
  // run and disable the upload button
  const evt = new CustomEvent('input')
  upload.dispatchEvent(evt)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
  This example shows how to clear a <code>file</code> input.<br>
  Click the 'Choose File' button to select any file. Once a file is selected, click the upload button.<br>
  <b>Note</b>: No real upload occurs. The button simply circles to <i>pretend</i> to upload and then resets the file input.
</p>
<div>
  <!-- Create a file input to work with -->
  <input id="upload" type="file">
</div>
<div>
  <!-- Create a button to mimic upload -->
  <button class="button" id="upload-btn" disabled>Upload</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful and helped me fix it